# Derived class type in template argument doesn't compile

Tags: c++, templates

This is the code snippet I have been hopelessly stuck on.

```
template <class T, T nt>
class C;

struct base{
   int i;
} b;

struct derived : base{} d;

C<base*,&d> obj;
```

Why this giving error `could not convert template argument &d to base*`?

Comment: long story cut short, an address only exists at runtime, template arguments must be evaluated at compile-time, uurk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When matching an argument to a parameter that is a pointer/reference, derived to base conversions are not considered even if the conversions are valid in other circumstances.

14.3/5 [Standard quote just for reference]

> If a non-type template-argument cannot be converted to the type of the corresponding template-parameter then the program is ill-formed.
>
> ....
>
> for  a  non-type template-parameter of  type  pointer  to  object,  qualification  conversions  (4.4)  and  the
> array-to-pointer conversion (4.2) are applied.  [Note: In particular, neither the null pointer conversion
> (4.10) **nor the derived-to-base conversion (4.10) are applied**.  Although 0 is a valid template-argument
> for a non-type template-parameter of integral type, it is not a valid template-argument for a non-type
> template-parameter of pointer type.  ]

Comment: So perhaps `&d` would better be passed as a constructor argument (when creating `obj`) rather than a template one.

Comment: I'm always amazed how fast *certain people* on SO have that correct standard references at hand.

Comment: @Xeo : Comparatively I am much slower than @Johannes Schaub, @James McNellis, @GMan, @Jerry Coffin etc when it comes to standard quotes.

Comment: @Prasoon: I didn't write "certain people" in italics for nothing. ;) But still, you did it in under 2 minutes, do you always have the std papers open and a ll annotations in mind?